# How to Debug Windows Service Build Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsPv.jpg)
I created a window service application. When I build it, it is showing this as the build result: Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
Meaning it is not building successfully. But when i installed it, it is installing successfully. But not running as it should run.

I need help on how to find what is making it fail during building, so that i can fix it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We need a more detailed error to help you.

Comment: What's the build error? Please include the offending code. If necessary, set the build output details to Diagnostic.

Comment: Please how do i set the build output details to diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking at the 'Output' tab of Visual Studio.

Try looking at the 'Error List' tab.

[image]

Comment: It is not showing any error. it is only showing this: Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped

Comment: What are you using to build? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: am finding it difficult to add an image to my question

Comment: Right - you are looking at the Output tab, not the Error List tab. Try going to View --> Error List (more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot it is building now and i have installed it successfully. But my problem is my code is not working as it is suppose to work. I wrote an application that is running a timer and it is logging a time into a file at an interval of 10seconds. But it seems it is not working, I don't knw what is the problem. Please how do i find what the is about

Comment: Not sure, you should probably create a new question specific to that problem (this question deals with getting a list of errors in visual studio). Make sure and post the code you have written, what you expect it to do, and what it is doing that you think is wrong.